# Testing promise result when result property is randomly generated

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, sinon-chai

I'm testing a function that returns an object result like

```
domainResult = {
    domainId: uuidv4,  
    domainName: string,  
    groupId: uuidv4,  
    status: string  
}
```

Within the function, the domainId uuid is generated so my normal method of

```
await expect(function(args)).to.eventually.become(domainResult)
```

doesn't work because any placeholder domainId uuid won't match what is actually generated in the function.
Is there a way to test the validity of the expected response despite this troublesome property?

One method that works is by setting the promise result to a constant, then testing the constant's individual property values. E.g.

```
result = await function(args);
expect(result.domainId).to.be.a.uuid('v4');
expect(result.domainName).to.eq('myDomain')
etc
```

However I'm trying to refactor the code and make it more condensed.

Answer (score 0):

The standard answer for this is mocking. The details here depend on the library you are using for unit testing.

In this example, you would mock the `uuidv4` module to return a fixed number during the runtime of this test, which you can then verify. Since you're using JavaScript, here is the documentation for mocking modules in Jest: https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks.

Another option would be via [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). This requires you to restructure your code, but can be a powerful tool. e.g. instead of a static function which directly calls to `uuidv4`, you might create a wrapper class, which has a member function for generating ids. In your tests, you could replace this function (e.g. by subclassing, or in other scenarios by replacing a instance pointer with a different implementation/mock) and test its output independently of the id generation.